# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(αx)}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)} \mathrm dx$ using Complex methods

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(αx)}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)} \mathrm dx. $$

I am not sure how to solve this question. Can anyone help me to approach this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Use $\cos(\alpha x)=\Re(e^{i\alpha x})$, and use partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: define

$$f(z)=\frac{e^{\alpha i z}}{(z+i)(z+2i)(z-i)(z-2i)};,\;$$

$$C_R:=[-R,R]\cup\gamma_R:=\{z=Re^{it}\;,\;0\le t\le \pi\}\;,\;\;R\in\Bbb R^+$$

Integrate on the above contour, and use (for example)

$$\text{Res}_{z=i}(f)=\lim_{z\to i}(z-i)f(z)=\frac{e^{-\alpha}}{2i\cdot 3i\cdot (-i)}=-\frac{e^{-\alpha}}6i\;,\;$$

and the other (simple) pole of the function within the above region and etc.

Then let $\;R\to \infty\;$ , use Jordan's Lemma and etc.

**Added on request:** We also have

$$\text{Res}_{z=2i}(f)=\lim_{z\to i}(z-2i)f(z)=\frac{e^{-2\alpha}}{3i\cdot 4i\cdot i}=\frac{e^{-2\alpha}}{12}i$$

Since using Jordan's Lemma we have that

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int\limits_{\gamma_R}f(z)dz=0$$

we get

$$2\pi i\left(-\frac{e^{-\alpha}}6i+\frac{e^{-2\alpha}}{12}i\right)=\left(\frac{e^{-\alpha}}3-\frac{e^{-2\alpha}}6\right)\pi=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int\limits_{C_R}f(z)dz=$$

$$=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ix\alpha}}{x^4+5x^2+4}dx$$

and now just take the real part of the above...Final answer:

$$\frac16\left(2e^{-\alpha}-e^{-2\alpha}\right)$$

Comment: Hi, I only learned the residue theorem from the complex variable, didn't learn the Jordan's Lemma. Can you give me a hint by using the Residue theorem to solve the problem please? Thank you for replying me.

Comment: Don, the answer should be even in $\alpha$, no?

Comment: What do you mean by "even in $\;\alpha\;$" , @RonGordon ?

Comment: Oh, I think I see: $\;\cos\alpha x=\cos(-\alpha x)\;$...ok.

Comment: This works only if alpha is positive, otherwise the gamma_R part explodes.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\cos\pars{\alpha x} \over \pars{x^{2} + 1}\pars{x^{2} + 4}}\,\dd x
=
{1 \over 3}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{\alpha x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
-
{1 \over 6}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{2\alpha x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
=
{1 \over 3}\,\fermi\pars{\alpha} - {1 \over 6}\,\fermi\pars{2\alpha}
$$
where
$$
\fermi\pars{\mu}
\equiv
\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic\verts{\mu}x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
=
\Re\bracks{2\pi\ic\,
\lim_{x \to \ic}{\pars{x - \ic}\expo{\ic\verts{\mu}x} \over x^{2} + 1}}
=
\Re\bracks{2\pi\ic\,
{\expo{\ic\verts{\mu}\pars{\ic}} \over 2\pars{\ic}}}
=
\pi\expo{-\verts{\mu}}
$$

$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\cos\pars{\alpha x} \over \pars{x^{2} + 1}\pars{x^{2} + 4}}\,\dd x
=
{1\over 6}\pars{2\expo{-\verts{\alpha}} - \expo{-2\verts{\alpha}}}\pi}
$$
ADDENDUM:
The integration is performed along the contour on the picture $\pars{~R > 1~}$. The contribution from the semicircle vanishes out in the limit $R \to \infty$. $\pars{~ +\ic\ \mbox{is the pole enclosed by the integration contour}~}$:
$$
\verts{\int_{\rm semicirc...}{\expo{\ic\verts{\mu}z} \over z^{2} + 1}\,\dd z}
<
\int_{0}^{\pi}{\expo{-\verts{\mu}R} \over R^{2} - 1}\,R\,\dd\theta\quad
\stackrel{R \to \infty}{\to}\quad {\large 0}\,,\qquad \forall\ \mu \in {\mathbb R}
$$
[image: Integration Contour]

Comment: Why the absolute value of $\;\alpha\;$...?

Comment: @DonAntonio: looks like Felix is assuming knowledge of the FT of $1/(1+x^2)$.  But the answer is correct.  To derive it, you need to use a semicircle in the lower half plane for $\alpha < 0$.

Comment: I see, @RonGordon, yet I'm checking, but analytically and with WA (yeah,I know...) that the result doesn't depend on the sign of $\;\alpha\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: nothing wrong with checking against WA.

Comment: Well, it is always risky, @RonGordon...in the last 4-5 months there have been some 4-5 cases of wrong results given by WA. It seems to have serious issues with some stuff.

Comment: @RonGordon "looks like Felix is assuming knowledge of the FT of 1/(1+x2)" Not sure about that, actually it seems the residue theorem is applied there, hence $2\pi i$ times the limit. But if your point is that this should be made MUCH more explicit before one could be sure this is useful to the OP, I fully agree (and of course, answering concerns voiced in the comments is not a crime, this is even recommended...).

Comment: @Did: Well, it looks like he's taken a hybrid approach, in that he is assuming he knows that the absolute value is involved so he shortcutted the answer, which I agree is of little use to the OP.  Yes, my point was that one needs to at least outline where the abs value comes from, i.e., the lower contour in the pos. sense, and not handwave it as it is done here.  It may be a bit tedious, but it is certainly nontrivial.

Comment: @RonGordon Well, since $\cos(\alpha x)=\cos(|\alpha|x)$, the absolute value might not be far below the surface... Having said that, I agree with everything else in your last comment.

Comment: @RonGordon The integral is an even function of $\large\alpha$. It means we just need to evaluate for one of two cases 1) $\large\alpha \leq 0$ or 2) $\large\alpha >0$. If we know that information from the very beginning, we we'll use it to make a short proof. My fault was not to indicate explicitly what was the contour integral because at that time it was pretty obvious. I agree that maybe is not so obvious for the OP. I'm collecting a few contours drawing to be used in the near future. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You consider the countor $\Gamma$ defined by a line from $-R$ to $R$ and then transversed counter-clockwise from $R$ to $-R$. We can parametrize the line segment by $\gamma_1(t) = t$ by $-R\leq t\leq R$ and the semi-circle by $\gamma_2(t) = Re^{i\cdot \theta}$ for $0\leq \theta\leq \pi$. Define $f(z) = \cos(az)/(z^2+1)(z^2+4)$ then, 
$$ \oint_{\Gamma}f(z) ~ dz = \int_{\gamma_1} f(z) ~ dz + \int_{\gamma_2}f(z) ~ dz $$ 
Evaluate LHS via residue theorem. Now, show that, 
$$ \int_{\gamma_1}f(z) ~ dz = \int_{-R}^R \frac{\cos(ax)}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)} ~ dx $$
You can then try to show that, 
$$ \int_{\gamma_2} f(z) ~ dz \to 0 \text{ as }R\to \infty $$
Now by taking the limit as $R\to \infty$ you should get, 
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(ax)}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)} ~ dx = \oint_{\Gamma} f(z) ~ dz $$
But the RHS is a known value via residue computation.

Edit: Use the function $f(z) = e^{iaz}/(z^2+1)(z^2+4)$ instead because we have to have the integral along $\gamma_2$ go to zero as $R\to \infty$. It will not be the case if we had $\cos(az)$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Can you use the complex variable theory and residue theorem, giving me the hint to solve the problem? Thanks.